# MissingMethodException using COM through Excel and VBA

Tags: c#, com, windows-server-2012, jit, missingmethodexception

I have a C# library from which I have exposed a couple of method to COM so that they can be called from Excel VBA. This library references another .NEt library from a 3rd party. This all works very nicely when deployed to a Windows Server 2016. When it is moved to an instance of Windows Server 2012 then I get a MissingMethodException when the JIT compiler attempts to JIT a method with a call to the 3rd party library.

I can compile the code on the target server and test it all fine, I can even call the code without any issues from another .Net application. It is only when it is called from the VBA code that it then fails to load and execute the 3rd party code.

I have changed the code in my library to do an Assembly.LoadFrom() on the 3rd part library and I can then use reflection to find the method. However, if I then invoke the method from the MethodInfo I get a failed result and on inspection in the QuickWatch Window I have a message "Internal error in the C# compiler". I can debug my code through executing Excel and stopping in my library and all seems fine except when trying to execute the method containing the code to the 3rd party library as the JIT won't compile it.

How do I debug why the JIT compiler can't find and load the assembly that I am using?

Comment: Both servers **definitely 100%** have the same version of the third party DLL installed?

Comment: Definitely 100% not, MissingMethodException is always a DLL Hell problem.  Discovering that you now also need to take care of getting the right version of somebody else's DLL deployed is quite common.  Irksome, but that's why they pay you the big bucks ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely the same version of the 3rd party DLL. I copied it over myself. It works if accessed via C# code but not when using the COM interface set up with Regasm.exe